# Count the no. of non empty nodeset in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, xpath, sharepoint-2010, xslt-1.0

There are 24 rows returned by my dataview webpart. There's a column called NoExperience which has a number type. For some rows, it has value for NoExperience and some rows don't contain value for NoExperience. I only need to count the number in NoExperience column that would indicate total # of non empty value for that column. Sort of COUNTA function in Excel.

I m using xsl 1.0.

Any help?Below is my line of code. This always return 24. There are 10 non empty values for NoExperience column. I need to find that number.

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row/@NoExperience)" />
```

In XPAth builder the value of @NoExperience shows like this:
; ; ; ; ; ; ; 6; 6; ; 6; ; ; ; 6; ; 7; 7; ; ; 9; 9; 9; 9;

There are 10 non empty values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably the "empty" case has `<Row NoExperience="">` rather than the attribute not being there at all, so you need something like

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row/@NoExperience[string(.)])" />
```

as a non empty string value will act as a true predicate.

Comment: Could you also please provide me little explanation? Thanks again.

Comment: well your original counted the number of NoExperience attribute nodes but NoExperience="" is a mode so got counted. `@NoExperience[...]` filters (and so counts) the node for which `[....]` is true. string(.) gives the string value of the attribute in a boolean context  empty strings are false and non empty strings are true so NoExperience="123" gets a true filter and NoExperience="" gets a false filter

Comment: Thanks David Carlist. I need to read more XSL. But I really appreciate your time in explaining it to me.